# Crop a picture on a previously made but complex shape in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, crop, shapes

I am currently developping a website in which the user would have the opportunity to upload their own picture in order for us to print them in stickers with a shape and dimensions we have already drawed. The user would just have to adjust his own picture in the outlined shape so that he could see the result before the printing.
I've seen many topic about cropping but they don't meet my expectations. In my case the shape is not always made of straigth lines but curves but is already designed in Illustrator.
What would be the best solution to realise that? Is that possible to do it in Jquery?

Comment: Hi, did you got any solution? I have to do a similar thing. I have to take part of a image which is adjusted in a outlined flag shape. To create flags of the image to be uploaded. See my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33820712/crop-a-image-in-a-specific-shape-net/33822158#33822158

Answer (score 0):

you can crop images by using HTML5 Canvas element

example http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/10/30/resizing-cropping-images-canvas/

Answer (score 0):

have a look at these existing questions and google search result, the link in the end is with 20 jquery plugins for image cropping.

**Says php, but using jquery, so you can use it in asp.net**
[Image cropping with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10264705/image-cropping-with-jquery)

[Is there a jQuery image cropping plugin similar to Facebook's image crop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7850673/is-there-a-jquery-image-cropping-plugin-similar-to-facebooks-image-crop)

**Lots of jquery image cropping plugins**
http://www.jqueryrain.com/demo/jquery-crop-image-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

What i am understanding is that you want user's picture to be set inside a frame(sticker) that you have made in Adobe Illustrator. You can join these two images by something like this

```
using (Graphics grfx = Graphics.FromImage(image))
{
    grfx.DrawImage(newImage, x, y)
}
```

See this for details : [Merging two images in C#/.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465172/merging-two-images-in-c-net)