# Crop an image by curve split lines for puzzle in winforms

Tags: c#, .net, image, gdi+, crop

I'm trying to crop an image in windows forms (C#). I did it with straight corners. But I want to split it with curve lines.

A Single image is split into a 3x3 image and then placed in 9 different pictureBoxes. Here is my current code:

```
Image img = pictureBox1.Image;
int widththird = (int)((double)img.Width / 3.0 + 0.5);
int heightthird = (int)((double)img.Height / 3.0 + 0.5);
Bitmap[,] bmps = new Bitmap[3, 3];
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        bmps[i, j] = new Bitmap(widththird, heightthird);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmps[i,j]);
        g.DrawImage(img, new Rectangle(0, 0, widththird, heightthird), new 
        Rectangle(j * widththird, i * heightthird, widththird, heightthird), 
        GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        g.Dispose();

    }

}
pictureBox2.Image = bmps[0, 0];
pictureBox3.Image = bmps[0, 1];
pictureBox4.Image = bmps[0, 2];
pictureBox5.Image = bmps[1, 0];
pictureBox6.Image = bmps[1, 1];
pictureBox7.Image = bmps[1, 2];
pictureBox8.Image = bmps[2, 0];
pictureBox9.Image = bmps[2, 1];
pictureBox10.Image = bmps[2, 2];
```

Q: **How can I can crop/split the image with curves and export the pieces?**

---

My output:

[image: My output]

I want it cropped like this:

[image: I want it cropped like this]

Comment: Please provide explanation/screenshot about what is it doing now, and the actual question. Thanks

Comment: i have uploaded the output and what i want it to be :)

Comment: I still don't understand, based on the output it seems that You are doing the splitting of image. What is the problem? What You expect?

Comment: if u see in the output. I have 9 picture boxes where the 9 bitmap images are placed and these picture boxes have straight border. I just want the border to be curved and crop the image accordingly. As in image "I want tit to be cropped like this".

Comment: A bitmap will always be rectangular. But you can make parts of it transparent to make them look irregular. How do you plan to represent the curves?

Comment: Can u please send me the code to make bitmaps curved and irregular. i have uploaded the image of how do I want it :)

Comment: @DanByström please send me the code or link how to do this

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33820712/clip-an-image-in-a-specific-shape-net